# jQuery Mobile - how do I submit forms to a URL and transit to another page inside the DOM?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile

in the jQuery mobile example. The page that will be displayed after a form is submitted is the same as where the form will be POST-ing/GET-ing to.

Is it posible to submit forms to a URL and transit to another page inside the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an event handler for the `submit` event for the form and submit the form manually, then manually transition to whatever page you want.

```
$(function () {
    $('#form_id').bind('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('path/to/file.php', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            $.mobile.changePage('#page_to_goto', {transition: 'slide'});
        });
    });
});
```

Some Notes:

- You may need to turn-off AJAX handling of the form by adding `data-ajax="false"` to the form tag.
- `e.preventDefault()` stops the form from submitting normally, a `return false;` at the end of the event handler should do the same thing.
- `$.post` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
- `.serialize()` - http://api.jquery.com/serialize/
- `$.mobile.changePage()` - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: thank you! actually, i figured out the question but stack overflow did not allow me to post after within 8 hours of posting the question. but your ans taught something that i didn't know. so..thanks!

Comment: What does the HTML look like in this case? Does the form tag need any action or method?

Comment: @xster In this case we use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the normal submission of the form. So at that point it's up to us to do something that will result in what the user sees. That's were we use the AJAX `$.post` method to submit the form to the designated URL (you could use the `action` attribute of the form if you didn't want to hard-code this URL). So the method is set by the fact we're using the `$.post()` method and the action is set as the URL passed into the `$.post()` method. Again however, you could just read the `method` attribute of the `form` tag to not hard-code the method.